Chain Logo image doesn't display in gnosis-safe-wallet UI
I am operating Safe-Infrastructure on my local end.
I already added chain info including chain logo image(there's file upload button for logo image) on the admin dashboard: http://localhost:8000/cfg/admin/chains/chain/add/.

All functionalities of safe-infrastructure are working properly, but the problem is that Chain logo image is not displayed in the safe-wallet-web UI.
When I go through the image logo URL directly, it occurs the following error:

Can you please check this and give me a resolution on that?
Thank you.
